# LINQ to SQL Connection String

Tags: linq-to-sql

I've used LINQ to SQL in a unit testing project to mock some test data. I've changed the database name today and consequently the LINQ to SQL code doesn't work any more. I get the following error **'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot open database "XXX" requested by the login. The login failed**'. I've tried changing the Connection property on the DataContext in the designer but this doesn't work. I've tried changing the connection string in app.config as well but this doesn't work as well. Is there anything I missing here?

Comment: I managed to solve this problem: In opened up the .dbml file in the XML editor (rather than the designer) and found a Database element with the old database name referenced. Once I changed this then everything was OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem: In opened up the .dbml file in the XML editor (rather than the designer) and found a Database element with the old database name referenced. Once I changed this then everything was OK.